# Is there an electric field near the surface of a AC current carrying wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

Is there an electric field near the surface of a AC current carrying wire ?
I thought that due to varying current the magnetic field will change thus this may induce an electric field in proximity of a wire ( or even not in proximity)
Please corrwct me if i am wrong anywhere

Comment: Can you specify what the current is doing exactly? "A current carrying wire" is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Yes when the magnetic field is changing, it will induce an electric field, which will induce a magnetic field, which will induce an electric field, and so on... An electromagnetic wave will be created, which radiates energy outwards into space.